# Catch error on serveFile function from node-static

Tags: node.js

Seems that the [documentation](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static#serving-specific-files) does not provide this information.

When using `serveFile` how can I check if the file served does exist?

```
fileServer.serveFile('/error.html', 500, {}, request, response);
```

In other words, how can I check if the file was served successfully?

Seems that [`serveFile` function](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static/blob/b51b8aeffb7cfd1d87d5b730226931a73e84b9a3/lib/node-static.js#L80-L95) doesn't accept a callback function. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the `serveFile` returns a "promise" (although it's not a promise, it's an instance of `EventEmitter`) so you can listen for the `error` event on that (it will fire when the file doesn't exist):

```
Server.prototype.serveFile = function (pathname, status, headers, req, res) {
    var that = this;
    var promise = new(events.EventEmitter);

    pathname = this.resolve(pathname);

    fs.stat(pathname, function (e, stat) {
        if (e) {
            return promise.emit('error', e);
        }
        that.respond(null, status, headers, [pathname], stat, req, res, function (status, headers) {
            that.finish(status, headers, req, res, promise);
        });
    });
    return promise;
};
```

If the file *is* served successfully, the `finish` method is called, and the same "promise" object is passed in to it. It will emit a `success` event:

```
Server.prototype.finish = function (status, headers, req, res, promise, callback) {
    // ...

    if (!status || status >= 400) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
        promise.emit('success', result);
    }
};
```

So, you can do something like this:

```
var promise = fileServer.serveFile('/error.html', 500, {}, request, response);
promise.on("success", function () {
    // It worked!
});
```

Comment: And for error I guess that `promise.on("error", function (err) {})` would work. Am I right?

Comment: @Johnツ - Yes, exactly.